# Why is the 'Gutenberg' Plugin generating an 'Inconsistent File Permissions' error when other Plugins, with the same permissions, do not?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, permissions, block-editor

Earlier, I logged into a WordPress Dashboard I manage and saw that WordPress' 'Gutenberg' Plugin required updating along with a couple of other Plugins.

All Plugins updated fine, with the exception of the 'Gutenberg' Plugin.  The error message, that was produced, was ...

> An error occurred while updating Gutenberg: The update cannot be installed because we will be unable to copy some files. This is usually due to inconsistent file permissions.

The error message was then appended with a list of Directories, which were affected by the inconsistent file permissions.

As such, I accessed the Web Files, via FTP as to check the File Permissions.  I noticed that the File Permissions for all Plugin Folders was set to `755` while all Plugin Files was set to `644`.

With this in mind, is anyone able to highlight why I could be having issues with the 'Gutenberg' Plugin, since it's Folder and File permissions are set to the same as the other Plugins; which are being updated with no problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you originally installed via FTP/Cpanel/CLI the directory and files may have a different "owner" belonging to "different group" than those installed via Wordpress.

One possible solution: If you have server access try deactivating Guttenberg and rename its plugin directory to something else. Then reinstall the plugin through Wordpress - if this works your Dashboard plugins page will list this plugin twice - activate the one with the newest version number. If this works you can then delete renamed directory and contents.

Comment: That seems to have solved the issue.  Thank you for your time! :-)